# Extract the last row in a dataframe with a timestamp before some given time

Tags: python, performance, datetime, pandas

Related questions: [I need to take specific row from different df to generate new df. How can I make my code faster?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277147)

I want to take the last data before the specified time from different time intervals df:

`generate_data` is for demo purpose, `selecte_time` and `get_result_df` is for production application.

`select_time` and `get_result_df` needs to be run a few million times in total.

How can I make `get_result_df` execute faster? My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2022)
durations = ['T', '5T', '15T', '30T', 'H', '2H', 'D', 'W', 'BM']
datas = {}
time_selected = None


def generate_data():
    global durations, datas
    start_dt = '2018-01-01'
    end_dt = '2022-05-02'
    for duration in durations:
        datas[duration] = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start_dt, end_dt, freq=duration))
        datas[duration]['duration'] = duration
        datas[duration]['data'] = np.random.random(len(datas[duration])) * 100

    return


def selecte_time():
    global time_selected
    start_dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1)
    end_dt = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 2)
    idx = pd.date_range(start_dt, end_dt, freq='T')
    time_selected = np.random.choice(idx)
    return time_selected


def get_result_df():
    global durations, datas, time_selected
    t_df = {}
    col = ['duration', 'data']
    for duration in durations:
        df = datas[duration]
        t_df[duration] = df[df.index <= time_selected][col].iloc[-1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(t_df[duration] for duration in durations)

    return df


def main():
    generate_data()
    selecte_time()
    df = get_result_df()
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On my computer, the running time of `get_result_df()` is `204ms`, how can I speed up the running speed of `get_result_df()`?

```
%timeit get_result_df()
204 ms ± 4.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I optimized it, and the running time was reduced to `53ms`. Is there any room for improvement?

```
def get_result_df():
    global durations, datas, time_selected
    t_df = {}
    col = ['duration', 'data']
    for duration in durations:
        df = datas[duration]
        dt = df.index.to_numpy()
        dt1 = dt[dt <= time_selected][-1]
        t_df[duration] = df[df.index == dt1][col].iloc[-1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(t_df[duration] for duration in durations)
    return df
```

```
%timeit get_result_df()
53.3 ms ± 7.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It seems like a running time change from 204 to 53 ms is a decrease, not an increase.

Comment: What in your code is synthetic (presumably for demo purposes) and what is real? Specifically, is `generate_data` the only thing that would change for production application?

Comment: Yes, It's decrease. `generate_data` is for demo purpose, `selecte_time` and `get_result_df` is for production application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `np.random`; it's deprecated in favour of the new generator methods in the family of `default_rng`.

`durations = [` should be `DURATIONS = (`, i.e. a capitalised tuple.

Don't leave `datas` or `time_selected` in the global namespace.

`data` is already a plural, so don't write `datas`.

Add PEP484 type hints.

Don't use `np.random.random` with a post-multiply; once you have an RNG instance call `uniform` passing 100 for your maximum.

`selecte` is spelled `select`.

`selecte_time` is deeply inefficient: you create an array of millions of elements, only to select one and throw the works away. Instead, calculate a random datetime between your two endpoints.

`get_result_df` is also deeply inefficient. Your inner loop should be using a bisection of the kind that `search_sorted` offers. Neither `left` nor `right` exactly matches what you're doing, so you have to check and conditionally decrement after the bisection.

`col` needs to go away.

I'm not convinced that it's a good idea to pass a generator expression like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(t_df[duration] for duration in durations)
```

into the `DataFrame` constructor. You can build up lists for your new index and data columns, and pass those in directly.

Add unit tests.

### Suggested

Covering some of the above,

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
DURATIONS = ('T', '5T', '15T', '30T', 'H', '2H', 'D', 'W', 'BM')


def generate_data() -> dict:
    datas = {}
    start_dt = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
    end_dt = datetime.date(2022, 5, 2)

    for duration in DURATIONS:
        datas[duration] = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start_dt, end_dt, freq=duration))
        datas[duration]['duration'] = duration
        datas[duration]['data'] = rand.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=len(datas[duration]))

    return datas


def select_time() -> np.datetime64:
    start_dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1)
    end_dt = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 2)
    range_hours = (end_dt - start_dt) / datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    hour_selected = int(rand.integers(range_hours))
    time_selected = start_dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour_selected)
    return np.datetime64(time_selected)


def get_result_df(datas: dict, time_selected: np.datetime64) -> pd.DataFrame:
    index = []
    data = []

    for duration in DURATIONS:
        df = datas[duration]
        y = df.index.searchsorted(time_selected)
        while True:  # Executes between 1 and 2 times
            row = df.iloc[y, :]
            if row.name <= time_selected:
                break
            y -= 1
        index.append(row.name)
        data.append(row.data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'duration': DURATIONS, 'data': data},
        index=index,
    )
    return df


def main() -> None:
    datas = generate_data()
    time_selected = select_time()
    df = get_result_df(datas, time_selected)

    assert df.shape == (9, 2)
    assert tuple(df.duration) == DURATIONS
    assert tuple(df.index) == (
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 20:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-06-29 00:00:00'),
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        df.data,
        (
            2.41440894, 28.33886947, 56.0277365, 92.21785259, 84.13760397,
            44.99816704, 20.3228723, 6.17753546, 83.78495657,
        ),
    )

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### O(1) interpolation

Even a bisection is overkill. You already know that the temporal index is linear, so you can simply interpolate. This is O(1) in time.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
DURATIONS = ('T', '5T', '15T', '30T', 'H', '2H', 'D', 'W', 'BM')


def generate_data() -> dict:
    datas = {}
    start_dt = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
    end_dt = datetime.date(2022, 5, 2)

    for duration in DURATIONS:
        datas[duration] = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start_dt, end_dt, freq=duration))
        datas[duration]['duration'] = duration
        datas[duration]['data'] = rand.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=len(datas[duration]))

    return datas


def select_time() -> np.datetime64:
    start_dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1)
    end_dt = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 2)
    range_hours = (end_dt - start_dt) // datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    hour_selected = int(rand.integers(range_hours))
    time_selected = start_dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour_selected)
    return np.datetime64(time_selected)


def get_result_df(datas: dict, time_selected: np.datetime64) -> pd.DataFrame:
    index = []
    data = []

    # Assuming that get_result_df has no knowledge of generate_data.
    # If it does, just pass these endpoints in.
    start_dt, end_dt = datas['T'].index[[0, -1]]
    target_fraction = (time_selected - start_dt)/(end_dt - start_dt)

    for duration in DURATIONS:
        df = datas[duration]
        y = int(target_fraction * len(df.index))
        for time, datum in df.data.iloc[y::-1].items():  # Executes between 1 and 2 times
            if time <= time_selected:
                index.append(time)
                data.append(datum)
                break

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'duration': DURATIONS, 'data': data},
        index=index,
    )
    return df


def main() -> None:
    datas = generate_data()
    time_selected = select_time()
    df = get_result_df(datas, time_selected)

    assert df.shape == (9, 2)
    assert tuple(df.duration) == DURATIONS
    assert tuple(df.index) == (
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 20:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-16 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-07-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2018-06-29 00:00:00'),
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        df.data,
        (
            2.41440894, 28.33886947, 56.0277365, 92.21785259, 84.13760397,
            44.99816704, 20.3228723, 6.17753546, 83.78495657,
        ),
    )

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @jaried It's possible to write a faster algorithm, but that depends on what corners you can cut in the input data based on what they are in real life. You haven't spoken to this in your question. Will the real data always have a datetime index that's linearly uniform? And have you measured both the bisection and interpolation implementations?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's my Fault,`get_result_df` in `Suggested code` takes only 5ms, It's very fast.
 The real data time is not linear, only the specified time period. I'll resubmit a question.

Comment: I resubmitted a question, can you please take a look at it?  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277147/